# How can I pass data from dynamic <Link> to a component without displaying the data in the url in Next.js 14?

Tags: url, next.js, path, next.js14

I would like to pass category but without displaying it in the url.

```
<div className={styles.categories}>
    {categories.map((category) => {
      const categorySlug = category
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(' ')
        .join('-')
        .replace(/[()]/gm, '');
    
      return (
        <Link
          href={{
            pathname: `/categories/${categorySlug}`,
            // query: category,
          }}
          className={styles.category}
          key={category}>
          {category}
        </Link>
      );
    })}
</div>
```

I don't want '/categories/jane-doe?category=Jane%20Doe' because I think it’s not clean. Or what is the best way to approach this?

`pathname: '/categories/jane-doe'`

`category = Jane Doe`

`categorySlug = jane-doe`